# Rollback published VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I made a VS Code extension and published it in the marketplace. After issuing an update, I realised that there was a bug in that release. I want to roll back the update and get the users back to the previous update. Is there any chance of it, without sending another update with a new version number?

Comment: update your code to the previous version and release again with a version number bigger than the buggy version

Answer (score 0):

As rioV8 indicated, probably easiest to move forward with publishing a new fixed version

Comment: thank you! that's what i did. i was searching for other options where i don't have to increment the version number. i mean, that's fine with me, but if there's an option to rollback an update, it would be good.anyways, thanks for the advice!